# Lighttpd WARNING: unknown config-key: proxy.forwarded (ignored)

Tags: port, mod-proxy, lighttpd

I encountered an error that proxy.forwarded is an unknown key I already enabled mod_proxy on my configuration. Here is my config

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_accesslog",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_proxy"
)

$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/" {
    proxy.server = ( "/" => (( "host" => "0.0.0.0", "port" => 5000)))
    proxy.forwarded = ("for"  => 1, "proto" => 1)
  }
}
```

My lighttpd version is lighttpd/1.4.45

Comment: please verify with the [manual](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy) it looks for for me you did not used the correct way

Comment: Sorry proxy.forwarded and proxy.header is available on version 1.4.46. My bad

Comment: solved with my hint? ;)

Comment: Hi.  It's 2022.  The latest lighttpd release is lighttpd 1.4.66.  lighttpd 1.4.45 was released in Jan 2017, over 5 years ago, and there have been TWENTY-ONE (21) lighttpd releases since then.  Do you update your software much?